# Liquibase generating changelog of SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, database, maven, liquibase

I'm trying to do a reverse engineering of an existing SQL Server database, to start using Liquibase for database updates. I'm using the Maven plugin to do generateChangeLog on the different databases, but one of the databases gives me this error:

> view with
>   liquibase.statement.core.GetViewDefinitionStatement@7640a5b1: Error
>   executing SQL exec sp_helptext 'dbo.TableName': There is no text for
>   object 'dbo.TableName'.

Mind you, I interchanged the actual table name with TableName.

I have been using all SQL Server JDBC drivers I could find, the JTDS as well as the Microsoft drivers. All give me this error.

From what I've gathered [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e691c92a-807d-416c-8b36-161433287c3c/sphelptext-there-is-no-text-for-object?forum=transactsql), there is some corruption in the existing database. Is there any way to either fix or circumvent this? Mind you, all I'm trying to do, is generate a database changelog out of this, so we can use it locally to quickly set up a developers database.

Comment: OK, I managed to generate a view from a database in another environment, but the question still stands. It appears that the corruption is in the views that were made for the database.

Comment: Hi - I work a lot on the Liquibase source, and I'm curious what you would expect Liquibase to do when a database is in this sort of 'invalid' state. This seems like a valid response to me, and what I would have suggested is that you fix it by fixing the database. Would you want to have a --keepGoing flag or something for Liquibase so that it could just ignore errors and create the changelog anyway?

Comment: Well, bluntly said, yes. It is a valid response, I'm not disagreeing with you, don't get me wrong. I'd just like a "skip warnings/errors" flag of some sort. The database itself doesn't seem to be in a complete invalid state, since the production database has the same problem. Anyway, I'd be much better off if Liquibase would offer me (at least a partial) changelog, and I could correct the errors myself.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll add that to Liquibase JIRA as an enhancement request.

Comment: Added to Liquibase JIRA: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2241